# Export PATH and EMSCRIPTEN

Tags: command-line, bash

I am confused about PATH setup.

I was installing **emscripten** and following their tutorial.
As the last step you export variables running `source ./emsdk_env.sh`
This exports couple of things:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable
:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/clang/fastcomp/build_master_64/bin
:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master:"
EMSCRIPTEN="/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master"
```

After that I can access couple of commands like `emconfigure`

*When I exit the terminal, however, I can no longed use the command*. So apparently it only works for the current terminal session.

I read online that you can use `/etc/environment` for your scripts.
And so I did add it there similar to this:

```
PATH="/...../:emscripten_paths...:"
EMSCRIPTEN="/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master"
```

But then it had no effect. Rebooted, same thing.

Then I read you can add it to `~/.profile`
And so I did:

```
export GOPATH=...:
export PATH=$PATH:...
export EMSCRIPTEN=$HOME/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master:
```

And then: `source ~/.bashrc`
It still does not do anything for me. (Command is not found :s)

Now I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

I set the variables in `~/.bashrc`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/clang/fastcomp/build_master_64/bin:/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master"
EMSCRIPTEN="/home/gogromat/Downloads/emsdk_portable/emscripten/master"
```

and sourced it, and now it seems to work.